# Can anybody show how primary decomposition of ideals is useful. Any application?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, noetherian

So far I have been able to only see some standard counter examples or examples of Lasker-Noether decomposition theorem ( primary decomposition ). Why should someone care to learn it? ( I am being forced to do so by exams )

Comment: Why would anyone want to understand how to factor integers? Why understand directly irreducible rings? Why study atoms and subatomic particles? See any common theme here?

Comment: At least it's useful in algebraic geometry. I think people should tell him its application in more advanced courses.

Comment: @user1 It's answered in MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/7313/what-does-primary-decomposition-of-sub-modules-mean-geometrically